# Form data ignores ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, dynamic-forms

I am trying to utilize dynamic form and have used the following in AngularJS:

```html
<dynamic-form 
  template="formTemplate"
        ng-model="formData"
        ng-submit="processForm()">
</dynamic-form>
```

controller:

$scope.formData = {};   // JavaScript needs an object to put our form's models into.

$scope.formTemplate = [];

function onsuccess(response) {
      console.log('User reg form :'+ response);
      // This is the id of the form, it will be converted to string
     // var form-id = response.form-id;
      var result = toArray(response);
      $scope.formTemplate = result;

```
}

function toArray(obj) {
  var result = [];
  var model = [];var type = [];var label = [];
  for (var prop in obj) {
    var value = obj[prop];
    angular.forEach(obj.fields, function(val,key){
        if(val.field_type != ''){type.push(val.field_type);}
        else{type.push(0);} 
        model.push(key);
    });
  }
  for(var j=0;j<model.length;j++){
    if(type[j] === 'textfield' || type[j] === 'password'){
        type[j] = 'text';
    }
    else if(type[j] === 'email'){
        type[j] = 'email';
    }
   else{
      type[j] = type[j];
   }

    console.log("result.. " + model[j] + "......"+ type[j]);
     result.push(
       {
           "type": type[j],
           "label": model[j],
           "model": model[j]
       }
     );
  }
  console.log("Result..." + result);
  return result;
}
```

I am using this dynamic form : https://github.com/danhunsaker/angular-dynamic-forms

But, if I use the example given in it, it works buit above case doesn't work. What is going wrong here? model evaluation?

my response:

```css
 var response =        {  
   "form-id":"user_register_form",
   "fields":{  
      "name":{  
         "field_type":"textfield",
         "description":""
      },
      
      "mail":{  
         "field_type":"textfield",
         "description":""
      },
      "field_first_name":{  
         "field_type":"textfield",
         "description":""
      },
     "field_gender":{  
         "field_type":"radio",
         "options":{  
            "male":"Male",
            "female":"Female"
         },
         "description":""
      }
     
   }
}
```

Comment: could you show me what is display on this console.log --> console.log("Result..." + result);  it's on toArray function.

Comment: Its an array of object. Result...[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: e.g., first object if i print -  Result..[object Object]
 type...text
 label...name
model...name (key, value)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem because your result variable containing $resource object rather than regular object. Try this:

```
function onsuccess(response) {
  var result = toArray(response);
  $scope.formTemplate = angular.toJson(result);
}
```

Comment: any error come up after the change? could you add console.log($scope.formTemplate); after the line above?

Comment: could you tell me where is the onsuccess function executed?

Comment: after getting dynamic response from $http response, in RegisterCtrl.

Comment: is onsuccess function locate in RegisterCtrl (same scope)?

Comment: could you add {{formTemplate}}, right before <dynamic-form line.
and tell me what is display after $http response finish executed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112656/discussion-between-smitha-and-mtamma).

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer, for those finding this now, is that the library in use doesn't properly support re-rendering the form when the template changes. There are a number of things to keep track of when re-rendering a form, especially one which already has data in it, and I never got around to figuring them all out properly.

At this point, I recommend against using my library, and instead using one of the libraries mentioned in the alternatives section of its README. They are generally better made and more up to date.